# Pull Request is closed, delete fork

Tags: github, git-fork

I closed a pull request and I get message:

```
Pull request closed
If you wish, you can delete this fork of SomeNewAPP in the settings.
```

If I want to do this I should go to the Settings and click Delete this Repository, right?

But if I still have few more Pull Requests opened, will I delete them as well?

Thank you!

Comment: Are your other pull requests on this fork or on the original repo?

Comment: @Annemie they are all on that fork. So I will delete them as well, right?

Comment: If you delete the fork (the copy of the original repo), you will delete all the pull requests, branches and commits on that forked repo. I would not delete it in your case as you still have work in progress on the current fork.

Note that deleting a forked repository will not delete the original repository or any other repositories that you may have created or forked. Each repository exists independently, and deleting one repository will not affect others. If you have other open pull requests in different repositories, deleting a forked repository will not affect them.